# Strip number characters from start of string in list

Tags: python, list, strip

```
my_list = ['1. John',
 '2. James',
 '3. Mark',
 '4. Mary',
 '5. Helen',
 '6. David']
```

I would like to remove the number that is a string, the `"."` and the white space before the name.

```
for i in my_list:
  i.lstrip(". ")
```

I was hoping the output would be a list as such:

```
mylist = ['John', 
  'James',
  'Mark', 
  'Mary',
  'Helen',
  'David']
```

Comment: You could `split` at the space and only use the second part or give `lstrip` all characters (including digits) to strip from the beginning of the string.

Comment: @laclanthony use triple ```` to start and end a block code and single ` for inline code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use strip, you can try:

```
my_list = ['1. John', '2. James', '3. Mark', '4. Mary', '5. Helen', '6. David']
name_list = [item.lstrip('1234567890. ') for item in my_list]
```

Or as @Michael Butscher mentioned, to retrieve the name part you can simply use split to split the string by space into two part `['1.', 'John']` and retrieve the last part:

```
name_list= [item.split(' ')[-1] for item in my_list]
```

Result:
`['John', 'James', 'Mark', 'Mary', 'Helen', 'David']`

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex.

```py
import re

regex = re.compile(r'(\d+).\s')
my_list = ['1. John', '2. James', '3. Mark', '4. Mary', '5. Helen', '6. David']
new_list = [re.sub(regex, '', item) for item in my_list]
print(new_list)

# Output: ['John', 'James', 'Mark', 'Mary', 'Helen', 'David']
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def strip_numbers(my_list):
    result = []
    for i in my_list:
        x = i.split(". ")
        result.append(x[1])
    return result
print(strip_numbers(my_list))
```